# How to build Knowledge graph UI using angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I have a requirement to build knowledge graph UI using Angular. I am using Blazegraph database and wanted to achieve something like the below image where user can add new nodes to the existing nodes and have functionality to drag the nodes:

[image]

Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Uumsqo1aiA

Please suggest how can I get started with it. Also, if there is any third party apps to achieve this using angular.

Comment: You can use `d3-org-chart` package for your case. And I have added the screenshot of example.

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion you can try the GoJS for knowledge graph UI. Ref links mentioned below:

Option 1:
https://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartEditor.html.
To Use GoJS in Angular please click on the below link.

https://gojs.net/latest/intro/angular.html

Option2:
You can use the `d3-org-chart` alternatively, For more information please click on the below link.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-org-chart

Screenshot of the `d3-org-chart` example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info Saravanan. But, I needed to build knowledge graph where user can have flexibility to add, delete and drag the nodes. Please watch this video for the reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Uumsqo1aiA